# use python to access mysql

Tags: python, mysql

i am finally starting with python. 
i wanted to ask if i use the mysql db with python, how should i expect python to connect to the db?
what i mean is, i have mysql installed in xampp and have my database created in mysql through php myadmin. now my python is in C:\python25\ and my *.py files would be in the same folder as well. now do i need any prior configuration for the connection?

**what i am doing now**

```
>>> cnx = MySQLdb.connect(host=’localhost’, user=’root’, passwd=’’,  db=’tablename’)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

how do i need to go around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the basics is

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="nobodyknow", db="amit")
cursor = conn.cursor()

stmt = "SELECT * FROM overflows"
cursor.execute(stmt)

# Fetch and output
result = cursor.fetchall()
print result

# get the number of rows
numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)

# Close connection
conn.close()
```

and don´t use ’
use single or double ' ou " quotes

Answer (score 2):

If you simply cut and pasted, you have the wrong kind of quotes.

You've got some kind of asymmetric quote.

Use simple apostrophes `'` or simple quotes `"`.

Do not use **’** .

Comment: The path (C:\python25\\) tells us that Windows is being used. The substitution of so-called smart quotes for the real thing is one of Windows' more irritating habits.

Comment: This isn't a windows issue, its a blog/wordpress issue where he copied the original connection code from.  A lot of newer blogging engines pretty up the quotes if the poster isn't careful to identify a block as code.